# how to provide own image to svg for background?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am building a react app and there's a portion where I need to make a slanted div that also has a background image.

the shape is like the blue div shown here - [slanted div shape](https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oncode.it%2Fen%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F4%2F2017%2F10%2Flayout-svg.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oncode.it%2Fblog%2F4-ways-to-create-a-responsive-slanted-div-layout-with-html-and-css%2F&docid=zIC_-mdJXtxL7M&tbnid=pxed_NvCLtnO8M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjG2f2-oojeAhXLgI8KHc1GD48QMwhFKAowCg..i&w=804&h=327&hl=en-IN&bih=643&biw=1173&q=slanted%20div%20image&ved=0ahUKEwjG2f2-oojeAhXLgI8KHc1GD48QMwhFKAowCg&iact=mrc&uact=8)
Now, i could have done as shown in the image i linked to, but since there's a background image, i am unable to use that as i would have to use it in 2 divs.

so, i want to use svg to create the shape along with the background and then have other things like text in that div.
so, what should I do then to make that happen.

here's what I was trying but I am unable to show the background image and the slant at the same time.
just wanted to add that this svg is inside a grid like this. it's a material ui grid for layout. 
I want this image to take the whole space of this grid as the background image that is. and I'd write text on this grid like i normally would.

```
     <Grid container > 

<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} className='mscbackground' > 

<h2> asfasfdasdfasfdasfd <span className='blueword'> ASDFASDFASDF</span> </h2> 
JLSAKSJFDKLAJSLKDFJALKSJFDKLAJSLKFDJALKSJFDLKJLKSDJFLKJALKSDJFLKAJSDLKFJALKSJDFKLAJSLDKFJaksjdflkajsldfkjalkdfjslakjdslkfjalksdjflkasjdfkljalskdjflkasjdflkjalksdjflkasjdlkjflkasdjflkajsdlkfjalksdjflkasjdlfkj 


</Grid> 



</Grid>
```

and in css I have used

```
.mscbackground {
    height: 450px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    line-height: 2.5;
    text-align: center;
    color: #D9D9D9;  
    width:100%;
    background:
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#fff 50%) bottom/100% 7% no-repeat,
     url('./assets/black-and-white-music-headphones-life.jpg')center/cover no-repeat;
  }
```

but it's not working. the background image isnt showing at all.

so, any ideas how to make this work??

Comment: Would helpful if you showed your code, how do we know what the elements look like, where the svg is in relation to the rest, if it's being applied in html or css etc

Comment: have added the whole grid item now to the original post

Comment: so, any ideas then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add background to `path`. Using SVG you can consider clip-path like below:

```css
svg {
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="circle"> 
       <polygon points="0,0 300,0 300,100 0,200" fill="white" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
<image width="300" height="200" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=0" clip-path="url(#circle)"/>
</svg>
```

In case you don't need transparency here is an easy solution with CSS:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#fff 50%) bottom/100% 40% no-repeat,
   url(https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=0) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: react isnt allowing me to use this xlink:href=                     inn the image tag

Comment: @faraz I added another  solution, you may check it

Comment: any idea how to make the slant not so steep?

Comment: @faraz try to adjust the value `49%` make it a bit bigger or small `48.5%` or `49.5%` until you get what you want

Comment: could you just answer one more ? the text isnt staying in the box, but going outside it. why is that? and when I am putting padding-bottom then I see a border line below. why is that? could you explain a bit or point me to a link which better explains this technique in linear gradient?

Comment: @faraz show me the full code so I can see and help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181890/discussion-between-faraz-and-temani-afif).

Comment: if you put some more data in the box div, then you'll see it's going outside.

Comment: @faraz remove width:100% https://jsfiddle.net/5g3pusoq/3/ .. or add `box-sizing:border-box` if you want to keep the width

Comment: but will it still be responsive if I remove width:100%

Comment: @faraz by default a div is 100% width .. or keep it and add `box-sizing:border-box`